# Running mstsc in background

Tags: python, windows, automation

I need python script to run mstsc in background without showing mstsc(RDP) screen to user.
Script will contain remote computer name, username and password written and the moment the script is run, mstsc(RDP) should run in background.

I have tried pywinauto but it is using mouse control and keyboard control.

I expect that after running mstsc in background, remote computer should be displayed on my computer window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://cloudbase.it/freerdp-for-windows-nightly-builds/
Have not tried the windows version of the client - but if that one works you have a lot more options on the command-line.